# I want to know if this is possible using firebase or not?

Tags: firebase

Thinking to Create project using Firebase but need to confirm , it will fullfill my requirement or not . So it will be like there will be numbers of groups and in each group there will be 5-15 devices connected . so if any of the devices from the group does anything that should get updated to every device in that particular group so everyone gets to know what has been done and from which device. ALL the Logs will be generated on the FCM server .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this with Firebase. You database should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
      |
      --- groups
      |     |
      |     --- group1
      |     |     |
      |     |     --- groupName: "G1"
      |     |     |
      |     |     --- Devices
      |     |           |
      |     |           --- deviceId1: true
      |     |           |
      |     |           --- deviceId2: true
      |     |           |
      |     |           --- deviceId3: true
      |     |
      |     --- group2
      |           |
      |           --- groupName: "G2"
      |           |
      |           --- Devices
      |                 |
      |                 --- deviceId4: true
      |                 |
      |                 --- deviceId5: true
      |                 |
      |                 --- deviceId6: true
      |      
      --- devices
             |
             --- device1
             |      |
             |      --- deviceName: D1
             |      |
             |      --- groups
             |            |
             |            --- group1: true
             |            |
             |            --- group2: true
             |            |
             |            --- group3: true
             |
             --- device2
                    |
                    --- deviceName: D2
                    |
                    --- groups
                          |
                          --- group4: true
                          |
                          --- group5: true
                          |
                          --- group6: true
```

With this database structure, you can easily display all the groups from `groups` node and all the devices from the `device` node. You can also display very easy all the devices that belong to a single group and the groups in which a device exists.

Having the database strcutured like this, you can then use FCM to send messages to all devices from a particular group.

Hope it helps.

Comment: SO it will be 2 way communication right ? Devices to server and server to device ?

Comment: Thanks Alex Mamo. i will start doing it and if you have any idea for pursuing this will save alot of time of mine. thanks in advance :)

Comment: If have more questions don't hesitate to ask. If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks